# Assign dynamic array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to pass following payload to the API

```
params[field1]: value1
params[field2]: value1
....
params[fieldN]: valueN
```

I have field and value coming from an object.

```
var params = {};
jQuery.each($scope.linkParams, function(a, b) {
    params.params[a] = b; // returns undefined variable error
    // I also tried other options but all result in one or another error
    // Some doesn't result into an erro but doesn't get merged. See below merge requirement
});
```

I also wants to merge the above created object to another object with

```
jQuery.extend(extraParams, params);
```

How to achieve the rquired object?

**Update**

```
$scope.linkParams = {
    field1: 'value1',
    field2: 'value2',
....
};
```

Comment: Based on the code snippet, you could just create `var params = {params:[]};`. This should get around the undefined variable error. But there may be other things you need to do too

Comment: Updated question with `$scope.linkParams`

Comment: @Rhumborl I coped up with the undefined issue, but I am not getting the actual result.

Comment: Your syntax is correct for your Object, are you sure you are declaring every thing properly? Try to declare `params.params = [];` and `var $scope = {};` as well as `$scope.linkParams = {};`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for ya http://jsfiddle.net/theclap/9yxyzbu2/

Comment: @theClap Yes, everything is well declared. I tried the jsfiddle too. The object gets prepared but, merge is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions, so I'll address them one at a time.

*(For a TL;DR, I emboldened the solution text. Hopefully the rest is worth the read, though.)*

### Object Serialization is Pretty Magical, but Not Quite That Magical

If I had a JS object that I instantiated like the following:

```
var cat = {
  'meow': 'loud',
  'type': 'Persian',
  'sex': 'male'
}
```

then it is certainly true that you get attribute reference for free. That is, you can say something like `cat.meow`, and your runtime environment will make sense of that. However, JS will not automatically create properties of an object that you have referenced do not exist, unless you are referencing them to create them.

`cat.health = 'meek'` will work, but `cat.ears[0] = 'pointy'` will not.

```js
var cat = {
  'meow': 'loud',
  'type': 'Persian',
  'sex': 'male'
}
cat.health = 'meek'
alert(cat.health)

cat.ears[0] = 'pointy'
alert(cat.ears[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You'll notice that the first alert happens and contains the expected value, but the second alert never comes. This is because the code fails on the line with `cat.ears[0] = 'pointy'`, and it stops execution at that point.

This may seem to contradict what I just said, but look closely at what's happening. When we attempt to initialize the first element of `cat.ears`, we must reference the `cat.ears` property, which does not exist.

JS implementations won't assume that you want to create items up the chain eternally, which is likely by design -- if it didn't throw errors and instead just created any properties or objects that needed to exist in order for your program to by syntactically sound, many pieces of software would silently break when they failed to include required libraries. If you forgot to include JQuery, it'd just create a `$`, a `JQuery` variable, and all of the properties of those objects you reference in your code. It'd be a proper mess to debug.

In short, that's what you're -- probably accidentally -- assuming will work here. `params.params` is analogous to `cat.ears` in the above example. You may have some reason for doing this, but assuming you don't, your code should function if you **simply change `params.params[a]` to `params[a]`**.

### JQuery.extend()

Assuming that `extraParams` is a valid array/object, **the code you have written will work** once `params` doesn't break your code anymore, *however:* do note that this will modify your `extraParams` object. If you want a new object to contain both `params` and `extraParams`, **write something more like**:

```
var args = $.extend({}, params, extraParams)
```

That will modify an empty object and add in the contents of `params` and `extraParams`. See [the JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) for more information.

Comment: I don't really have any idea why I included JQuery. Lol.

Comment: All variables are valid and well declared, also its not breaking. I also don't want another object with merged result.

Answer (score 0):

Some manipulations and I was able to achieve the required results.
I am posting the code for further reference:

```
var d = {};
jQuery.each($scope.linkParams, function(a,b) {
    a = "params[" + a + "]";
    d[a] = b;
});
jQuery.extend(extraParams, d);
```